# How do I compile ALSA 1.0.24? 

Tags: compiling, alsa

I'm using Ubuntu Maverick on my main PC, and I got the system configured just the way I like it (yay!) a long time ago. Everything was well until the recent Wine releases which are apparently made to use ALSA 1.0.24 which is sadly not available for Maverick. This means I lost all sound in Wine, which is not nearly as funny as it should be!

I found [this tutorial](http://duopetalflower.blogspot.com/2011/02/alsa-1024-in-ubuntu-1010.html) on how to build ALSA 1.0.24, but I'm not sure if the procedure is "safe enough" to use. By "safe enough" I mean "will it mess up my system beyond repair". Is the big red-lettered disclaimer in the beginning of the article justified? How dangerous is the procedure described? Should I risk it and give it a shot or just bite the bullet and install Mint from scratch, [like I did on my laptop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24967/moving-from-ubuntu-32bit-mint-64bit-or-mint-32bit) (successfully, it seems)?

**UPDATE:**

After following Gilles' advice below about trying to install ALSA binaries for Lucid, I had a bit of a problem with sound being blocked for other apps when playing something in Flash. To fix this, I did the following:

Create `/etc/asound.conf` with the following content:

```
pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.!default { type pulse }
ctl.!default { type pulse }
```

Then simply restart ALSA with the following command:

```
sudo alsa reload
```

I found all this on [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455816) but chose to restart ALSA instead of the whole system, and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is grossly exaggerated. The main problem with it is that it will install files under `/lib` and`/usr`, overwriting some files provided by the Ubuntu distribution. This means that it won't be easy to uninstall or upgrade your manually installed drivers. I recommend specifying `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` when compiling the library and the utilities, so that everything you install that isn't part of the distribution is under `/usr/local`. For the drivers, you don't have this luxury: they must be under `/lib/modules`, but fortunately these aren't so critical.

Nonetheless, I suggest carefully reviewing and keeping note of what files are being installed. Run `make -n install` to see this, before running `sudo make install`. Alternatively, install the [`stow`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/stow) package, create a directory `/usr/local/stow/alsa-1.0.24`, give yourself write permission on it (e.g. `sudo chown hannibal /usr/local/stow/alsa-1.0.24`), specify `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/alsa-1.0.24`, and run `make install` without `sudo`. Then run `sudo stow alsa-1.0.24` from the `/usr/local/stow` directory. Finally, symlink the modules under `/usr/local/stow/alsa-1.0.24/lib/modules` to the corresponding directory under `/lib/modules` and run `sudo depmod -a`.

Compiling the packages from the upstream source is not the easiest solution.
There's a [PPA with Alsa 1.0.24 packages for lucid](https://launchpad.net/~team-iquik/+archive/alsa?field.series_filter=lucid); those binary packages might work on maverick. Or you could try recompiling the [1.0.24 packages from natty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/natty/alsa-driver).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Can you tell me how to try the binary packages for Lucid? Are .deb files installable if they are meant for a different version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter See the generic [PPA installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_PPAs). Packages don't contain an indication of what version of Ubuntu they're for; you can install them on another version if the dependencies are met (I haven't checked whether this is the case here).

Comment: It worked! I simply added the Lucid PPA and installed all the updates. I had no idea you can add PPAs for other versions.. Thanks, you saved my bacon! :)